# Table stretch and cell alignment with iText 7 PDF

Tags: c#, wpf, itext7

I need to generate product cards in pdf format using C#. So I chose iText 7. 
After reading the documentation, I tried to generate the first result, and that's what I got:

[image]

So, I have big white table with 4 cells - Image cell, Description cell, Additional cell, Price cell. Each cell has an inner light gray table with round corners.
For example, consider the description cell.

**1.** I want to stretch the inner table to the full height of the parent cell(description cell), but I can't, because I don't know height of this parent cell:

[image]

How can I do that with iText 7? Can anyone help me?

Here is the method of creating Description cell:

```
private Cell CreateDescriptionCell(string description)
{
    // Create description cell of the product
    var descriptionCell = new Cell()
        // Here if I set fixed height of the cell, then
        // the inner table tableDestionation will be stretch by height!!
        //.SetHeight(300)
        .SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
        .SetPadding(5, 10, 10, 5);

    // Create the table of the description
    var tableDestionation = new Table(1)
        .SetMargin(10)
        .SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100))
        // This only works when the parent cell descriptionCell 
        // has fixed height!!
        .SetHeight(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));

    // The header of the description table
    tableDestionation.AddHeaderCell(new TextCell("Описание",
        BoldFont, TitleForegroundColor, false));

    // The content of the description table
    tableDestionation.AddCell(new TextCell(description, 
        LightFont, RegularForegroundColor, false, TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED));

    // The renderer of the table. It added rounded corner to the table
    tableDestionation.SetNextRenderer(new RoundCornerTableRenderer(tableDestionation)
    {
        BackgroundColor = RegularBackgroundColor,
        Corners = new double[] { 5, 5, 5, 5 }
    });

    // Add the table of the description cell
    descriptionCell.Add(tableDestionation);

    return descriptionCell;
}
```

I updated my question

Comment: please share your code so someone can help you

Comment: I have a lot of code. Which one are you interested in? CustomTableRenderer? or what?

Comment: better if you provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I hope you're not creating one big table, but instead define four areas, adding the four parts at absolute positions. To reduce the file size if you have multiple pages with the same background structure, I'd work with a template that is reused as a Form XObject. We may not need your complete code, but we should at least know if you've made the right architectural choices. I you created everything in one big table, we'd know you probably made the wrong choice.

Comment: Now I have 5 methods - CreateImageCell, CreateDescriptionCell, CreateAdditionalCell, CreatePriceCell and MakeProductCard. The last one, create full table, using 4 Create method

Comment: I shared my create description cell code.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, and so, can you help me?

Comment: Not without rewriting your code, so: no, it would take too much time for me to spend for free.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, 
Can you advise which way to move? No need to write code for me

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: Also: why change the background of the inner table instead of changing the background of the cell? The inner table is smaller than the cell, which explains the result.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, if I change the background of the cell, the entire cell will be that color. And I need the background of the cell to be transparent, and only the inner table had a background

Comment: I repeat my earlier comment: work with a template that has the colored areas. Add the extra content on top of the colored areas.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, What do you mean by colored areas? In iText I have not seen such concepts. I only know about Table, Cell, Div, Paragraph, Text, Image, and other, no longer significant things, for my problem

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, I read about templates of the form PdfFormXObject, which you advised me to use. I tried to apply them in my code. These templates need to set the working area in the form of a Rectangle, ie to set the real dimensions, which I do not know initially. And what should I do?